# Extension methods for ReaderWriterLockSlim

Tags: c#, multithreading

In current project I'm using a lot `ReaderWriterLockSlim` for synchronizing reading and writing values. Handling `try { EnterReadLock(); .... } finaly { ExitReadLock(); }` every time I need access value seems to me as copying code. So I created extension methods for `ReaderWriterLockSlim` which makes me coding much easer and faster (and reusable i think).

However I would like know, if you found some disadvantages in the extension methods I missed or forgot.
There are three extension methods:

- `ReadOnly<T>(this ReaderWriterLockSlim self, Func<T> readFunc) // calls EnterReadLock()`
- `Read<T>(this ReaderWriterLockSlim self, Func<T> readFunc) // calls EnterUpgradeableReadLock()`
- `Write(this ReaderWriterLockSlim self, Action writeAction) // calls EnterWriteLock()`
- `Write<T>(this ReaderWriterLockSlim self, Func<T> writeAction) // calls EnterWriteLock()`

There is code of `ReadOnly<T>(...)` method. All methods looks similar.

```
public static T ReadOnly<T>(this ReaderWriterLockSlim self, Func<T> readFunc) {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(self, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("self"); }
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(readFunc, null)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("readFunc"); }

    T result;

    // flag, if lock was entered
    bool lockEntered = false;
    try {
        // I don't want the ThreadAbortException during claiming the lock
        Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
        try {
            self.EnterReadLock();
            lockEntered = true;
        }
        finally {
            Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
        }

        result = readFunc();
    }
    finally {
        // I don't want the ThreadAbortException during releasing the lock
        Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
        try {
            if (lockEntered) {
                self.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
        finally {
            Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: In cases like this, I prefer methods that work with `using`, instead of taking a delegate.

Comment: @svick, but working with using is not fully thread-safe :(

Comment: What do you mean? I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be thread-safe (assuming you don't use it incorrectly).

Comment: @svick: its because the using(var x = SomeFunc()){...} is only syntax sugar, when ThreadAbortException is thrown before object is passed from return value of "SomeFunc()" to local variable "x", the "finally{...}" block will not handle passed object, because in "x" is nothing (null).

Answer (score 3):

It looks pretty good. I can't see anything less than great.
I'd just add that to your code:

```
    private static void Critical(Action criticalAction)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
            criticalAction();
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
        }
    }
```

And i used the `IsWriteLockHeld`, `IsReadLockHeld`, etc, before exiting the lock.

Comment: Good point. Didn't you mean the "Thread.BeginCriticalRegion()" should be before "criticalAction()".

Comment: You got a point, there!